# Why everytime I need to restart chrony service in server machine to sync time to client machine?

Tags: linux, shell, ntp, rhel8, chrony

Let say I need to sync time between 10.201.x.x' (NTP server) and 10.203.y.y' (NTP client).
Everytime, I need to restart service on server machine to sync correct time.

```
2022-01-19T15:01:51Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-01-19T15:01:51Z Initial frequency -63.770 ppm
2022-01-19T15:02:00Z No suitable source for synchronisation
2022-01-19T15:02:00Z chronyd exiting
```

It says No suitable source even if the server is up and chronyd service is active also.
However, if I go to the server machine and restart the service using `systemctl restart chronyd` then this problem does not exist.

```
2022-01-19T15:05:10Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2022-01-19T15:05:10Z Initial frequency -63.770 ppm
2022-01-19T15:05:14Z System clock wrong by -0.001157 seconds (step)
2022-01-19T15:05:14Z chronyd exiting
```

So, I don't understand why this happening, I tried many methods also.